# Find isomorphism between $D_6$ symmetries of regular triangle, $S_3$, and $GL_2(F_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

problem: Find isomorphism between $D_6$ symmetries of regular triangle, $S_3$, and $GL_2(F_2)$.

I already proved $D_6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.

And $S_3 $ is isomorphic to $GL_2(F_2)$

Am I suppose to prove $D_6 $ is isomorphic to $GL_2(F_2)$ also?
Or can I say since $D_6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$ and $S_3 $ is isomorphic to $GL_2(F_2)$, then $D_6$ is isomorphic to $GL_2(F_2)$.

Thank you.

Comment: You can, but the question seems to describe explicitly this isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, you should construct an isomorphism between $D_6$ and $GL_2/\mathbb{F}_2)$, just to get more experience. Of course you know already that such an isomorphism must exist.

Comment: an isomorphism must exists because isomorphism obey the  transitive rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProofWiki has good advice: look at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Isomorphism_is_Equivalence_Relation under the subheading "Transitive".

Isomorphism is a transitive relation, and this section shows you the explicit isomorphism you're looking for.